# fetching data from same table multiple times?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch some data from a database table and use it in different sections on a page, currently I'm making multiple queries to fetch data from table, for example i want to fetch video path and description from videos table.
I've two functions,

```
function get_photo_path($id){
SELECT path from videos where id = $id;
return path;
}

function get_video_description($id){
SELECT desc from videos where id = $id;
return desc;
}
```

I'm just wondering if I can make a single function to fetch path and description together and use if in different sections, for example

```
<div><? //get path ?></div>
<div>some other data</div>
<div><? //get description ?></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function get_data($id) {
    $sql = "select path, desc from videos where id = $id;";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

    return $data:
}

$data = get_data($id);

?>

<div><?php echo $data['path'] ?></div>
<div><?php echo $data['desc'] ?></div>
```

Comment: will the `;` in the SQL cause an error?  Doesn't it automatically add one?  Or am I thinking of the PDO?  edit: [The query string should not end with a semicolon](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: I put it in from force of habit. It'd only strictly be necessary if you were doing multiple queries in a single call, which the mysql driver doesn't allow anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be. :)

```
$video = /* SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `id` = $id */;

<div><?php echo $video['path']; ?></div>
<div>some other data</div>
<div><?php echo $video['description']; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you have this at the top of the page:

```
<?
    // this isn't real mysql, so adjust to fit how you connect
    $sql = "SELECT path, desc FROM videos WHERE id = $id";
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));
?>
```

Then, when you want to print out the variables:

```
<div><?= $row['path']; ?></div>
<div>some other data</div>
<div><?= $row['desc']; ?></div>
```

Comment: Except mysql_query returns a result handle, not an array of results. You still have to fetch the rows.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said it wasn't real mysql.  I exclusively use the PHP PDO, so I am REALLY rusty on mysql and mysqli